# Submitting jobs in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, supercomputers

I want to analyze data from different files (let's say 10) which are not related to each other. I want to know what is the difference between submitting the jobs in parallel or opening 10 terminals and submitting the job 10 times. I want to know the difference related to running time assuming that I have more than 10 cores. I am not sure I understand the advantage of parallel programing in the case where the files don't depend on each other.

Comment: The advantage is that it is generally faster. The advantage of using a script with 10 jobs submitted and run in the background is that it is easier than opening 10 terminals.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for response. I understand it is easier with only one terminal. But I still don't understand why would it be faster that way than using 10 terminals?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. I don't think there is much speed difference between 1 Terminal with 10 background jobs and 10 Terminals each with a foreground job - other than it takes 10 times as long to start 10 jobs but if your jobs run for minutes or hours, the difference is negligible.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I understand. Thank you so much!